# cannot install vlc

Tags: apt, vlc

I got this error when trying to install vlc:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You have broken packages -- fix this before moving on. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#How_to_fix_broken_packages